# simple UDP server can't accept packets

Tags: c, linux, networking, network-programming

I have a simple UDP server program

```
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>


    int main(int argc, char**argv)
    {
       int sockfd,n;
       struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
       socklen_t len;
       char mesg[1000];

       sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

       bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
       servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
       servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
       servaddr.sin_port=htons(54000);
       bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

       for (;;)
       {
          len = sizeof(cliaddr);
          n = recvfrom(sockfd,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);
          sendto(sockfd,mesg,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
          printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
          mesg[n] = 0;
          printf("Received the following:\n");
          printf("%s",mesg);
          printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
       }
    }
    ~
```

I compile it

```
  gcc -m32 -o udp_server udp_server.c
```

and run it(`./udp_server`) on several linux machines, it works fine and I use  a udp client client to send packets  to the UDP server on these machines, they are accepted

but I have a new machine(let me call it A), it is relatively strange compared to other linux machines, as shown in  https://superuser.com/questions/581442/ifconfig-command-not-found
anyway it has no "eth0" and the interfaces are:

```
    [root@kitch proxy]# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1a:a0:23:86:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

First, I run the 32-bit-version of the program on it and I got

```
-bash: ./udp_server: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Then, second, I compile the UDP program without '-m32' and run it on the machine A, it runs normally
Then I use UDP client to send packets to the UDP server on A
I can capture the sent packets on this machine, but the UDP server doesn't accept those packets,

are there any potential reasons for this?
maybe the binding doesn't work here because this machine is special?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some recent Linux distros (e.g. Fedora) have changed the name of the interface from `ethX` to `emX`, so, nothing wrong with it.

You got problem with that machine because the server is not running at all as this line claims:

```
-bash: ./udp_server: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I guess you've compiled the program in a `32bit` mode ( look at the `-m32` `gcc` parameter ) in a `64bit` machine with no `32bit library support` installed.

Recompile it without `-m32` options.

Comment: I tried both, in my opinion, 32-bit machine should works in machine A, but why it can't? then I compile it and I run `./udp_server` successfully, just it can't accept UDP packets

Comment: How can you say it is running successfully? Without 32bit interpreter it can't run

Comment: I meant tried 2 versions.  I compile without `-m32` option on machine A, and then it runs successfully, but it can't accept UDP packets

Comment: Are the packets arriving to the machine A? Is the dst port correct? Try to shutdown the firewall for a test purpose (service iptables stop)

Comment: I can use tcpdump to capture the incoming UDP packets, so there is no firewall problem. and UDP port is correct. As I said before, I tried the UDP server on other several machines, and they can accept UDP packets correctly!